# Creating img src tag from Form inputs

Tags: php, html

I have a form that saves images in a folder on the server and the image info on a database.  What i would like to do is echo out the img src of the image after it was uploaded.  My question is Can i use the variables from the form itself and put them in the img src tag?

```
 $filetmp  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
 $imageName= mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $imageData=mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
 $imageType=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['type']);
 $filepath = "wp-content/uploads/2016/06/".$imageName;
 $url = "http://apklegion.com/";
```

what ive tried is this.

```
echo '<img src="$url.$filepath.$imageName" style= "width:200px;height:200px;">';
```

Which dosent display anything.

Comment: You can do that, but you have to use the right kind of quotes. Variables are expanded inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Comment: so double qoutes for each varible

Comment: Yes, `echo "<img src='$url$filepath$imageName' ...`. You don't need `.` inside quotes.

Comment: You also don't need both `$filepath` and `$imageName`, since you put `$imageName` into `$filepath`.